# добавить Button в NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

Как вот в такую структуру добавить view и button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы получилось вот так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сделать в Билдере, то ты уже сделал - просто перетащи `View` на `navigationItem` (на прямоугольник, на сам визуальный объект), потом на `view` перетягивай `UIButton`.

Из кода можно сделать так: делаешь `view`, на нее кладешь `UIButton`, потом делаешь `UIBarButtonItem` с помощью `init(customView customView: UIView)`.

Comment: Из билдера View не добавляется никак, зависает между кнопками  First responder и Exit.

Comment: из кода UIBarButtonItem юзать неудобно, потому что у нее не назначается ширина в коде, только визуально

Comment: 1) добавляется замечательно. Я специально проверял. Попробуй создать отдельный xib и проверить.
2) ширина UIBarButtonItem должна зависеть от ширины customView. Если и с какими-то ограничениями, то с разумными. Юзать вполне удобно

Answer (score 1):

```
  let barButtonOK = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self , action: "actions:")
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonOK]

  func action(obj: AnyObject) {
     //обрабатываете
  }
```